# PHP to MySQL date formatting issue

Tags: php, mysql, date, echo, strtotime

I have a PHP/MySQL date formatting problem. Here, i create the date variables:

```
$checkDate = date("d/m/y H:i", time());
$datestrto = strtotime($checkDate);
```

Then i insert it to a mysql table with the column Datatype of bigint.

When i then, later on, when i need to echo the date, i use this code:

```
echo '<td>'.date("d/m/y H:i",$row['f_uploaded_date']).'</td>';
```

But istead of echo'ing the date in the format `D/M/Y H:i`, it echo'es the date in the format of `m/d/y H:i`.
Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance,
Adam

Comment: Why the transformation in the first place and not inserting `$checkDate` directly?

Comment: Datatype you are saving is bigint i think that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert it into the MySQL table do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable(something,somedate) VALUES('something',str_to_date('".$checkDate."','%d/%m/%y %H:%i'))
```

and when you pull it out from MySQL then do it like this:

```
SELECT *,date_format(somedate,'%D/%M/%Y %H:%i') as formateddate from yourtable
```

then in php you use:

```
$row['formateddate']
```

Hope it helps you :)

**EDIT:**
The complete code:

```
$ddate = date("d/m/y H:i", time()); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO files (rowID, file, mimetype, data, uploaded_by, uploaded_date, size, times_downloaded, description) VALUES (NULL, '$fileName', '$fileType', '$content', '$user', str_to_date('".$ddate."','%d/%m/%y %H:%i'), $fileSize, 0, '$description')";
```

Comment: Hmm.. So like this?: `$date = date("d/m/y H:i", time()); $sql = "INSERT INTO files (rowID, file, mimetype, data, uploaded_by, uploaded_date, size, times_downloaded, description) 
 VALUES (NULL, '$fileName', '$fileType', '$content', '$user', str_to_date('".$checkDate."','%d/%m/%y %H:%i'), $fileSize, 0, '$description')";`

Comment: yes but you changed variable name to $date and in your insert it is $checkDate so be sure to check that :)

Comment: point is that "Theadamlt" better understand whats going on here and that he solves his problem.

Comment: Hi @FeRtoll, thank you for the help! col-shrapnel, i'm doing it this way, so i, later on, can compare dates

Answer (score 1):

So you convert a unix timestamp into a formatted date string then convert the formatted time string back into a unix timstamp and insert that into your database. Wouldn't it just be simpler to just insert the unix timestamp you got in the first place? Or not even bother with PHP code and

```
INSERT INTO sometable (id, f_uploaded_date) 
VALUES ($id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))
```

?

I suspect the explicit problem you describe is due to the fact that strtotime expects date strings of format 99/99/9999 to be the american style of mm/dd/yyyy rather than dd/mm/yyyy as used in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

First,

```
$checkDate = date("d/m/y H:i", time());
$datestrto = strtotime($checkDate);
```

is quite funny way of assigning `time()` frunction result to `$datestrto` variable.

Next, you don't need that variable either, as you just can use `unix_timestamp()` mysql function in the insert query.

Now to your question.

> istead of echo'ing the date in the format D/M/Y H:i, it echo'es the date in the format of m/d/y H:i.

double-check your syntax. there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: He is saving date as Bigint, i think that is creating the problem

Comment: bigint cannot be an issue. this field *can* store int numbers all right

Answer (score -1):

You can pull a date format from your mysql database and then when converting to a php variable you can use:

```
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

$i=0;
while ($i <= $num) {
$date=mysql_result($result,$i,"Date");
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
echo $date."<br>";
}
```

Where $result is your mysql query result and "Date" is the name of the column. However I am unsure of using this method with the time.

--EDIT--

link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: this method works, i did not copy any code and currently have this working on a website. This is my own. How is this answer offtopic? He is asking how to display a date from a MySQL date in a certain format and I have given a method of doing this.

Comment: he is NOT asking how to display a date from a MySQL date. **READ THE QUESTION**

Comment: He is asking how to output the date in a certain format "D/M/Y H:i" instead of "m/d/y H:i". I have done this excluding the time.  *He is asking how to display a date from a MySQL date in a certain format* *READ MY COMMENT*

Comment: He asks not for the code. he has the code already. he asks why doesn't it work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8668/discussion-between-philip-bevan-and-col-shrapnel)